# Where is timeline information stored in MS Project Server Database

Tags: ms-project, project-server, ms-project-server-2013

Which table/view can I pull "Display on Timeline" checkbox info from the Project Server Database? I can see all Task Information from [MSP_EpmTask_UserView], [pub.Task]. The only data I can not find is "Display on Timeline". Anyone has experience with that?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1uq0.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the timeline data in the table **pub.MSP_PROJECT_FRONT_END**

timeline data stored as XML format in **PFE_PROPERTIES** field

Answer (score 1):

Download the Project 2013 SDK from
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30435

In it is the full schema for the Project Reporting database. Look especially at all the Views ending with _UserView as they have custom fields added automatically.